# Get Link to a Facebook post from API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I am struggling with getting the link to a Facebook post from an API call like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/807247516000935/posts?access_token={TOKEN}
```

For most of the posts I can create the link with `"www.facebook.com/" + item.getId()`, but sometimes these kind of links don't work. Is there a rule how to create a link that ALWAYS works? I have the feeling that most of the links that don't work are posts, which contain a link to a Facebook post or page.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cases involved here:

1. **Using link**

   If you use the link (`www.facebook.com/{POST_ID}`) to see the post, you will be able to see the post only if the privacy setting allows current user to see the post. Eg:

   - If privacy setting is set to `PUBLIC`, any one can see the post with that link
   - If privacy setting is set to `ONLY ME`, no one can see the post with that link etc..
2. **Using Graph API**

   Unless the post is not deleted, you can query for the post details using (`graph.facebook.com/{POST_ID}?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}`) whatever be the privacy setting.

*Note*: If a post is deleted by the user, obviously you wont get any details of the post by any way

---

----Edit----

#### Differentiating between `photos` and `status`/`link`

When we wish to post a link or a status message, Graph API consider this as a **feed** and `\POST /feed` is used to post it.

And, if we wish to post a photo, `\POST /photos` is used.

BUT if we want to get the posts using `\GET /<ID>/feed`, it gives us **all** the timeline posts be it *link* or *status* or *photo*.

Now, if you notice carefully, the feed result has a key `type`, that tells you if its a link or a status or a photo. Also, if it's a photo, the API gives you another parameter: `object_id` which should be used to get a link to that photo.

So-

```
if type="photo"
   link="http://facebook.com/{object_id}"
else
   link="http://facebook.com/{id}"
```

Comment: I am using only public pages in my app. But nevertheless www.facebook.com/{POST_ID} does not work with all posts.

Comment: You mean that you are posting to a public page? Also, are you able to get the post using Graph API?

Comment: I am not posting to any page. I am just resolving data from the Facebook API, display post and link to these posts.

Comment: If you can provide an example page/post

Comment: Yeah, one example is this page: https://www.facebook.com/www.Christian.Weber.de. When I try to link to his last post with https://www.facebook.com/807247516000935_862717677120585 the links does not work.

Comment: Check the edit.. PS. in above example, the link would be: https://www.facebook.com/862715883787431

Comment: Thanks, I will try this later after work. But I really can't understand why Facebook does not deliver a field with an always working link to the post.